# Datatables - Length (select option) outside datatable

Tags: datatables

I am using DataTables and I would like my length(select option) to outside of the table

(ex. on my div).

Comment: You mean, you need a custom `select` drop-down that should act like the native datatable length dropdown box.

Comment: More important is why you need the length (select option) to be outside the table. What features you want to add or remove from the original one?

Comment: I want to move it to navbar.

Answer (score 10):

create new select form

```
<select name='length_change' id='length_change'>
    <option value='50'>50</option>
    <option value='100'>100</option>
    <option value='150'>150</option>
    <option value='200'>200</option>
</select>
```

init dataTables

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({});
```

set initial value

```
$('#length_change').val(oTable.page.len());
```

add function .change

```
$('#length_change').change( function() { 
    oTable.page.len( $(this).val() ).draw();
});
```

reference : https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()

Comment: This worked for me. In case anyone is using the previous jQuery datatable API (dataTable with a lower case 'd') then adding api() to the function will work. Like this:

`oTable.api().page.len( $(this).val() ).draw()`

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be directly moved by just copying the whole change length drop down outside the table.

Instead create a new drop-down, where ever you want but set the following in the datatable call -

```
  <select name='length_change' id='length_change'>
        <option value='50'>50</option>
        <option value='100'>100</option>
        <option value='150'>150</option>
        <option value=''>All</option>
    </select>

`var oTable = $('#sample_1').dataTable( {
.....
"bLengthChange": false,       //This will disable the native datatable length change
.....
...
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "length_change", "value": $('#length_change').val() } );
},
.....
....
});
`

The `aoData.push` will send the selected value of the customer length change to the server.

In the Model Class from where the array will be returned for the datatable, include the pushed value to the limit.

i.e. if `$postData` is the array of posted values to the server then -

`if($postData['length_change'])
    $limit = (int) $postData['length_change'];
 else
    $limit = _DEFALUT_VALUE;
```

`

I hope it helps.